# Python, Pyodbc - encoding rows to json

Tags: python, tornado, pyodbc

```
class GetAdminAsJsonHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        admin_guid = self.get_argument("admin_guid")
        if admin_guid == None:
            self.write("AdminGuid is missing.")
        else:
            database = self.connect_db()
            cursor = database.cursor()
            admins = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Admin").fetchall()
            self.disconnect_db()
            self.write(json_encode(admins)) # Error
```

Hi, I should develop a handler that returns json encoded list of admins in database when requested by AJAX from web.  With using Pyodbc and assuming the table columns are AdminGuid, ID, and Name,  how should I correct that #Error part to make it work?

Thanks!!

*Error Msg

```
[E 141021 02:22:47 web:1407] Uncaught exception POST /admin/get (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8000', method='POST', uri='/admin/get', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Origin': 'http://localhost:8000', 'Content-Length': '12', 'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate', 'Host': 'localhost:8000', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8000/admin', 'Cookie': 'csrftoken=NUV1oVLBJ3jzzvuNio9Dv22k8qTt5TYW; install_421aa90e079fa326b6494f812ad13e79=bqgjn14u6t5sn3th0ccdnj6pr7', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1332, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\SANG MIN\Desktop\haundae\module\admin\handlers.py", line 34, in post
        admin_array = [a for r in admin] = {}
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\escape.py", line 88, in json_encode
        return json.dumps(value).replace("</", "<\\/")
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
        return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
        raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    TypeError: ('admin', 'admin', '\xc3\xd6\xb0\xed\xbf\xee\xbf\xb5\xc1\xf8', True, True, 1) is not JSON serializable
[E 141021 02:22:47 web:1811] 500 POST /admin/get (::1) 1233.00ms
```

Comment: What's the error message? Show us the whole traceback message.

Comment: Added the error msg. TypeError: ('admin', 'admin', '\xc3\xd6\xb0\xed\xbf\xee\xbf\xb5\xc1\xf8', True, True, 1) is not JSON serializable. I guess it's not in an appropriate format to be converted to JSON

Answer (score 1):

http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2012/03/11/generate-json-from-sql-using-python/

This is what I wanted.  Hope it helps other people in the same trouble